# How to get test file name and line number from a fatal error caused in a test with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am currently PHPUnit for a project that I just joined in. Running the the PHP Unit gave me this result below:

```
PHPUnit 4.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /home/notalentgeek/notalentgeek/PHPProject/phpunit.xml

EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE..EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE   61 / 2244 (  2%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  122 / 2244 (  5%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE...  183 / 2244 (  8%)
...........EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  244 / 2244 ( 10%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  305 / 2244 ( 13%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE..EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  366 / 2244 ( 16%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  427 / 2244 ( 19%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  488 / 2244 ( 21%)
EEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  549 / 2244 ( 24%)
EEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  610 / 2244 ( 27%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  671 / 2244 ( 29%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  732 / 2244 ( 32%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE....  793 / 2244 ( 35%)
..EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE............EEEEEEEEEEE  854 / 2244 ( 38%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  915 / 2244 ( 40%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEE................................................  976 / 2244 ( 43%)
............E................................................ 1037 / 2244 ( 46%)
........................................................EEEEE 1098 / 2244 ( 48%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE................. 1159 / 2244 ( 51%)
...........................................................E. 1220 / 2244 ( 54%)
E............................................................ 1281 / 2244 ( 57%)
..........................EE...............E................. 1342 / 2244 ( 59%)
............................................................. 1403 / 2244 ( 62%)
............................................................. 1464 / 2244 ( 65%)
............................................................. 1525 / 2244 ( 67%)
..................................PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in MyOutdatedPHPFile.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 NotUnitTest.php(272): MyTool::Something('Hello World');
#1 NotUnitTest.php(40): cafe->makeMeATea('chinese tea')
#2 NotUnitTest.php(99): Something->hello('world')
#3 NotUnitTest.php(168): Other->test('3')
#4 NotUnitTest.php(628): MyClass::something()
#5 NotUnitTest.php(633): MyClass in NotUnitTest.php on line 73
```

There is a fatal error but the thing is that it does not show at which test file it occurs. What I want, for now, is to exclude the test that causes the fatal error. Hence, **I want to locate which test file and which line cause the error**. How can I achieve such thing?

Comment: file name is given there:- MyOutdatedPHPFile.php and line number also given :- 73 (but you need to check 2-3 line above as well as 2-3 line down too)

Comment: That is not the unit test file. I think, somewhere there, a test file calls a function inside MyOutdatedPHPFile.php and gives the mentioned error. I need to know which test file calls a function inside MyOutdatedPHPFile.php.

Comment: This could be caused by missing PHP Mcrypt module.

Comment: Yes, the module is deprecated and no longer in recent PHP. I want to know which test file accessed that mcrypt method.

Comment: it's in the Stack trace

Comment: What stack trace? Where should I put my stack trace in? In which file?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should **update PHPUnit.** It is at version 6.5 currently.

### Stack Trace

Your stack trace looks strange. Usually, it contains the complete paths, for example (I downgraded PHPUnit to get comparable results):

```
PHPUnit 4.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function doIt() in /home/path/to/project/tests/unit/bug.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /home/path/to/project/tests/unit/FooTest.php(8): Foo::buggy()
#1 [internal function]: FooTest->testFoo()
#2 /home/path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(865): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(FooTest), Array)
#3 /home/path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(743): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
#4 /home/path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(609): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#5 /home/path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(699): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(FooTest))
#6 /home/path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(722): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#7 /home/path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(7 in /home/path/to/project/tests/unit/bug.php on line 6
```

Here you can clearly see, that the error occurred in line 6 of `bug.php`, which was called from line 8 in `FooTest.php` with the call `Foo::buggy()`.

Following this, the call you're looking for is in `NotUnitTest.php` in line 272, where it calls `MyTool::Something('Hello World')`.

### Use the Power of your IDE

If you can't solve the strange output in your stack trace (the missing paths), you can still use your IDE to find the test file in question.

Find the method in `MyOutdatedPHPFile.php` that contains line 73. Then let your IDE search for usages of that method. If your IDE does not support usage search, either change the IDE or use text search for `->methodName(`. In any case, you'll get a list of files containing calls to the method in question - one of them is the file you're looking for.